# IE10 & 11 rendering issue with SVG text and textLength attribute

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I have SVG files created by converting AI files to SVG. They contain text elements with rectangles around them. To get the text to show the correct height and width the textLength attribute is used. When you interact with the text element in IE 10 & 11 the text resizes to the size it would be if you did not have the textLength attribute. This does not happen in IE 9 or Edge or in Chrome.

Simple example https://jsfiddle.net/Jeff672/zze9xroo/ Mouse over the text in IE 10 or 11 you will see the problem.

[Correct and incorrect text display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1tC2.png)

Full Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    text:hover { cursor: pointer; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="svgGraphic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="600"
         height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 200">
    <rect x="5" y="10" height="52" width="510" style="fill:aliceblue; 
          stroke:red;" />
    <text x="10" y="50" textLength="500" font-size="50"
          style="font-family: Arial,san-serif; fill: #000000;" >
           Testing Internet Explorer</text>
     </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from Microsoft was

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7256245/

*Hello and thank you for providing us with the feedback.
We are not working on IE feature bugs any longer unless they are security related. As a result this item will be closed out as a Won't Fix.*

My fix for the issue was to convert the textLength attribute to a transform scale.

Get the actual text length without the textLength attribute figured in (MeasureString below does not account for styling)

scaleX = divide the value in the textLength attribute by the actual text length.

Add a transform="scale(scaleX)" to your text element and remove the textLength attribute.

```
public static System.Drawing.SizeF MeasureString(XElement element, bool ignoreTextLengthAttribute = false)
{
        if (element == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.Value))
            return new System.Drawing.SizeF();

        // NOTE: presentation attributes have less weight that style
        double fontSize = 12;
        if (element.Attribute("font-size") != null)
        {
            double doubleOut = 0;
            if (double.TryParse(element.Attribute("font-size").Value, out doubleOut))
                fontSize = doubleOut;
        }

        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText
        (
            element.Value,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            new Typeface("Arial"),
            fontSize,
            Brushes.Black
        );

        if (!ignoreTextLengthAttribute && element.Attribute("textLength") != null)
            ft.MaxTextWidth = double.Parse(element.Attribute("textLength").Value);



        return new System.Drawing.SizeF((float)ft.Width, (float)ft.Extent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text {
      cursor: default !important;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Adding this css worked for me in ie, I tried on your example and it also worked

Comment: Your style does stop the text changing size but you have stopped the interaction with the text element. The problem is I need to interact with the text element. I have updated the jsfiddle to include your style and interact with the text element on mouse over using js. This causes the text to expand again.

Comment: I see what you mean. I found that it actually works in IE if you use the currentColor property value. I know this is a kinda crappy solution, but may help. https://jsfiddle.net/zze9xroo/59/